# SQL get last rows in table WITHOUT primary ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row

I have a table with 800,000 entries without a primary key. I am not allowed to add a primary key and I cant sort by **TOP 1 ....ORDER BY DESC because it takes hours to complete this task**. So I tried this work around:

```
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT int, @OFFSET int
SELECT @ROWCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(field) FROM TABLE)
SET @OFFSET = @ROWCOUNT-1


select TOP 1  FROM TABLE WHERE=?????NO PRIMARY KEY??? BETWEEN @Offset AND @ROWCOUNT
```

Of course this doesn't work.

Anyway to do use this code/or better code to retrieve the last row in table?

Comment: Quote by Joe Celko: *if it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table* - live by it!

Comment: haha good one. Unfortunately I didn't make this table..I acquired it and I am not allowed to add a primary key.

Comment: Can't you just add a regular, non-clustered, non-unique index instead? That would speed things up.

Comment: If it's taking hours to get the last record in a 800.000 (table) pile, the missing primary key is not your only problem. For your problem at hand, can't you add an index?

Comment: wat are you using to determine what the last record is? the record number sql server provides when you do a select * from the table?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to add a primary key? Unless this is a COTS product where you would lose the vendor support, I would push back on that. Of course for your problem, a primary key is moot as that does not indicate the order the records were inserted necessarily. It's usually close but record 34567 could get inserted after record 34568 if the transactions are close in time. The id is gotten at the start of the transaction not the end.  Or Ids can be manually inserted when moving new client data. The only reliable way to get the last record is to have an InsertedDate field.

Comment: HLGEM: Its a live server with data inserted/updated every few seconds/minutes. Also there are are 20 stored procedures, 3 cascading update/delete/insert triggers,  and 15 constraints, on the table, so besides the downtime, too many unknowns if the there is a problem with the new table.

Comment: DFORCK42: I determine the last record by count, and then I wanted to subtract it by an offset of 1. ORACLE has a simple rownum command, but its missing in MS SQL, so I have no way to associate the counted number to something in the database.

Comment: Rsenna: It is non-clustered indexed, however its not fast enough to sort by DESC with so many rows.

Comment: @user719825 - if you depend on something like rownum to determine the record order, you are bound to get into trouble sooner or later. The record order of a result set is arbitrary without `ORDER BY` *(arbitrary should read as, shouldn't be depended on)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you are saying 'last rows', you mean 'last created rows'.

Even if you had primary key, it would still be not the best option to use it do determine rows creation order.
There is no guarantee that that the row with the bigger primary key value was created after the row with a smaller primary key value.
Even if primary key is on identity column, you can still always override identity values on insert by using 
`set identity_insert on`.

It is a better idea to have timestamp column, for example CreatedDateTime with a default constraint.
You would have index on this field.
Then your query would be simple, efficient and correct:

```
select top 1 *
from MyTable
order by CreatedDateTime desc
```

If you don't have timestamp column, you can't determine 'last rows'.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help. I really couldnt do much other then sort by primary key.I was allowed to add it, and it gets the job done. If I have to select who answered the question the best, I guess I'll give it you for the good advise.

Answer (score 14):

If your table has no primary key or your primary key is not orderly... you can try the code below... if you want see more last record, you can change the number in code

```
Select top (select COUNT(*) from table) * From table
EXCEPT
Select top ((select COUNT(*) from table)-(1)) * From table
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an Index, can you?

Even if you don't have a primary key an Index will speed up considerably the query.

You say you don't have  a primary key, but for your question I assume you have some type of timestamp or something similar on the table, if you create an Index using this column you will be able to execute a query like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE timestamp_column_name=(
     SELECT max(timestamp_column_name)
     FROM table_name
)
```

Comment: `Top 1` is needed, as the query will return more than one row if more than one last rows were created simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select 1 column from a table of 800,000 rows where that column is the min or max possible value, and that column is not indexed, then the unassailable fact is that SQL will have to read every row in the table in order to identify that min or max value.

(An aside, on the face of it reading all the rows of an 800,000 row table shouldn't take all that long. How wide is the column? How often is the query run? Are there concurrency, locking, blocking, or deadlocking issues? These may be pain points that could be addressed. End of aside.)

There are any number of work-arounds (indexes, views, indexed views, peridocially indexed copies of the talbe, run once store result use for T period of time before refreshing, etc.), but virtually all of them require making permanent modifications to the database. It sounds like you are not permitted to do this, and I don't think there's much you can do here without some such permanent change--and call it *improvement*, when you discuss it with your project manager--to the database.

Comment: I may be able to create a view. As long as I do not add anything to the main tables, the view may work because I could add a primary key there.....Let me try that! Thanks

Comment: Be wary, as Indexed Views can be tricky to implement and support. SQL Books Online will help with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to edit this table, have you considered creating a view, or replicating the data in the table and moving it into one that has a primary key?

Sounds hacky, but then, your 800k row table doesn't have a primary key, so hacky seems to be the order of the day. :)

Comment: that is still not going to tell you anything about the order the records were inserted in.

Comment: This wont work? I thought if I INSERTED all the data into the view, wouldn't it hold the same order as the original table? Then I could add a primary key. Would the view update automatically as new data is inserted into the original table? If so, then It should be fine right?

Comment: @user719825: It would work, yes, but it wouldn't work as you'd expect, as SQL Server will just add the table data in the order that it retrieves it, in lieu of an `ORDER BY`. And this is the main problem. Unless you know what to order by, you can't really do it correctly.

Comment: Ok there is no easy way to do it. I had to add a primary key and implemented it at midnight last night. No problems.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you could write it simply as

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Hope it helps.