# Select the last two records in sql server when there is no identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data:

```
Name  Desc
Daman XXXX
Sam   XXXX
Ram   XXXX
Sun   XXXX
```

Output:

```
Name Desc
Sun  XXXX
Ram  XXXX
```

There is no identity column. So far I have tried the below but its not helpful

```
select *, Rank() over(order by Name ) as [Rank] from testdaman
```

Comment: To logically pick the last 2 rows, you need to specify an order.  In this case, there is no guaranteed way of extracting `Ram` and `Sun`, unless you have a way of expressing an order that makes it so those 2 rows are the first (or last) 2 rows of a query.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't. You need to use an auto-increment or timestamp to know the inserted order.

Comment: Impossible unless you add a column (like an IDENTITY column, or a datetime column with default current_timestamp). SQL Server has no concept of "last row"... a table is an unordered set of rows. So, if you want to reliably pull the last two rows, you need to change the table (or add a trigger that logs inserts somewhere).

Comment: @AaronBertrand datetime could give him a colision of results, due transaction inserting way, timestamp would be a better choice.

Comment: if I specify an order so the result will get change if a new row is added with a different alphabetical order.

Comment: @AndrewPaes Ties can be dealt with easily - this is why we have `WITH TIES` in the syntax, for example. You can also use `DATETIME2` for more granularity and much less chance for collision. `TIMESTAMP` isn't the answer - you do know that `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server actually contains *zero* information about date or time, right?

Comment: @nik_boyz: If you don't have a reliable column value that provides you an order, then your rows are ***not*** ordered, as much as it may seem so.  Unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, you have no guarantees that your rows will always be returned in the same order.  You're asking for trouble if you make that assumption.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050341/when-no-order-by-is-specified-what-order-does-a-query-choose-for-your-record

Comment: In sql server 2008 is an undocumented and unsupported %%physloc%% column. Maybe this could help you.

Comment: Also `TIMESTAMP` (better called `ROWVERSION`) columns change on update. Thus they would be unreliable for determining anything about initial insert of a row.

Comment: @MichałSzkudlarek How does that help you? Physical ordering != logical ordering, nor is it reliable to indicate time of insert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL get last rows in table WITHOUT primary ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870853/sql-get-last-rows-in-table-without-primary-id)

Answer (score 2):

`order by (select null)` is not actually ordering your records, it is used because `row_number()` requires an `over` and `order by` clause. No order is guaranteed, but you may find that the order is the same as the order the records were inserted in.

```
select top 2 *
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) [row]
  from testdaman
) T
order by [row] desc
```

Original Answer - requires SQL Server 2012 and above

```
select *
from testdaman
order by (select null) -- No order applied, but offset requires the order by line
offset (select count(*)-2 from testdaman) rows fetch next (2) rows only
```

Comment: Neary there :) but still it is showing Ram then Sam it must show sam then ram ( last row then second last row).

Comment: @nik_boyz - I added another query, let me know if it works out