# Fetch only 2 results, one for each different value of a concrete field

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MYSQL table with those 5 fields: `id, user_id, date, type, uid` where `type` can be `1` or `2`, I'm looking for a single query where I can fetch 2 results, one for type=1 and another one for type=2 based on date field.

Right now i have the following query which only gives me the last uid without taking care of the `type` field.

```
    SELECT t.uid
    FROM table AS t
    WHERE t.user_id = 666
    ORDER BY t.date
    DESC LIMIT 1
```

Does anyone know how should modify this query so i can get the last uid for type=1 and the last one for type=2 based on date field? I would like to keep a a single query

Comment: You could either use `user-defined variables` to create a row number per `type` or probably the easiest solution would be to use `union`...

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056885/select-the-last-two-records-in-sql-server-when-there-is-no-identity-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i updated the query following this "paradigm":

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html
http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/

This is how the query ended up:

```
SELECT s1.type, s1.uid  
FROM t AS s1  
LEFT JOIN t AS s2 ON s1.type = s2.type AND s1.date < s2.date  
WHERE s2.date IS NULL;
```

Here's a visual example: http://hastebin.com/ibinidasuw.vhdl

Credits are for `snoyes` from `#sql` on `Freenode`. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Union all` is probably the simplest method:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.user_id = 666 and t.type = 1
 order by date desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.user_id = 666 and t.type = 2
 order by date desc
 limit 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I updated the post, i need to fetch 2 results one for each type value, one for type=1 and another one for type=2. The union all was something i already tried but it didn't look too clean to me. I was wondering for something cleaner and good performance.

Comment: For your purposes, the `union all` is probably best.  An index on `user_id, type, date)` would help performance.

Comment: I've just posted a cleaner solution, just in case it interests you or anyone else. I've always felt like most people uses UNION to achieve results they don't properly know how to do it so i'm not an UNION enthusiasts. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time :)